# How to apply css transformations on HTML elements using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code:

```
<input type="text" name="name" required>

<div class="form-error-cont">
    <p class="form-err">
        <i class="icon-remove"></i>
        <span class="text">Your name is required.</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Now, when the form is empty, I'm adding a `animate` class to the `form-err` class with jQuery.

When the `animate` class is there, I want to individually animate both the `i` and the `span` elements inside - with CSS.

How is that possible? Any special css selector is needed here?

Comment: `.form-err.animate .icon-remove { opacity: 0; }` ? I'm hesitant to post it as an answer because I'm not sure if this is what you mean.

Comment: Sure it's possible, no "special" css selector needed. I suggest you do some research on "transition" and "transform" CSS properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use the `css transformation` on `i` and `span` separately.

i have modified your code please take a look, here is your answer.

**Html:**

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="input" required>
<button id="btn">
 Check
</button>
<div class="form-error-cont">
<p class="form-err">
    <i class="icon-remove">i </i>
    <span class="text">Your name is required.</span>
</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.form-err{
 opacity:0;
 transition:0.2s all linear;
 }
.animate{
 opacity:1;
}
.icon-remove,
.text {
 display: inline-block;
 transition: transform 500ms;
 transform: translateY(50px);
 }
 .text {
  transform: translateY(-50px);
}
.animate .icon-remove,
.animate .text {
 transform: translateY(0px);
}
.icon-remove {
color: red;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
$('#btn').click(function(){
var val = $("#input").val();
if(val==''){
$(".form-err").addClass("animate");
} else{

}
});
});
```

Working Fiddle **[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m_tanzi/zafgp93h/)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how you want to animate it, but I have create a fiddle you can easily edit yourself.

https://jsfiddle.net/room1tfv/2/

You can check with `$('input').val();` if an input is empty.

Currently the class gets after when it's empty, but from what you are saying you might want to reverse it.

Feel free to comment and ask for changes!

Comment: Put your code in the answer itself so answer is self contained. Use demos only to support what is actually in the answer